# Problems with common symbols in shared-library loaded dynamically using dlopen

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I am looking at the legacy build infrastructure which prohibits having common symbols in building dynamically loadable shared library (built with -fPIC).
(Build infrastructure prohibits having 'nm libtest.so | grep " C "'. Another module loads this shared library using dlopen(libtest.so). )
And I need help understanding why it is a bad idea to have common symbols in libtest.so.

I see that all uninitialized globals in library are common symbols but they should get initialized to NULL while loading the library. Or is there something more I am missing here.

Comment: What is a "common symbol"?

Comment: All uninitialized global symbols in the library are common symbols.According to nm:  "C"

The symbol is common. Common symbols are uninitialized data. When linking, multiple common symbols may appear with the same name. If the symbol is defined anywhere, the common symbols are treated as undefined references.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is your build system.  Specifically, why does it have that check?